# List the sql output columns in a specific order. The order of the columns are kept on another table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables as below. The first table holds the order of the SQL columns I want to output. The second table has the transaction data with matching column names to the first table. Note: All the column names in the second table is a data row in the first table and matched to the "TableColumnName" field. Client can change the output order of the columns from zGenericOrder table.

E.g. Country is the first column I want to output from the zAddress table as it is the column I want to output first (this is kept in zGenericOrder table)

Pretty much my final output required, based on this example is something like below. This requires to do dynamically.

```
SELECT  Country,FirstName,LastName,Suburb,Address1,Address2 FROM dbo.zAddress
```

Is this achievable using SQL only?

[image]

Comment: Yes this is *achievable* with dynamic SQL, although why you would want this level of complication is unusual, what happens if you suddenly want a column ordered descending? How often does the ordering need to change to warrant it being dynamic? Why not order data in the application, like you probably should? Looks like an XYProblem

Comment: This is something that is usually done in the presentation layer, not in SQL. It's not impossible, but just usually not the correct place to do it.

Comment: Almost always, leave presentation concerns to the *presentation layer*. Which should be accessing columns by *name* anyway to retrieve the data, not by ordinal position.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We have 100s of clients and each client can configure the order differently. When you set the ordering for the client, they usually do not change the order. OK, I will do the output ordering in the code rather in SQL. Just out of curiosity as well, would love to know how to do using SQL too if one of you can provide bit of insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple dynamic sql exercise:

```sql
-- Prepare data
select *
into zGenericOrder
from 
(
    VALUES  (1, 2, 1, N'Country')
    ,   (1, 3, 2, N'FirstName')
    ,   (1, 4, 3, N'LastName')
    ,   (1, 5, 4, N'Suburb')
    ,   (1, 6, 5, N'Address')
    ,   (1, 7, 6, N'Address2')
) t (ClientID, id,OrderBy,TableColumnName)

select *
into zAddress
from 
(
    VALUES  (1, N'John', N'Nash', 23, N'AubumRd', N'Sydney', N'Australia')
    ,   (2, N'Johnny', N'Bing', 34, N'KappRd', N'Sydney', N'Australia')
) t (Id,FirstName,LastName,Address,Address2,Suburb,Country)


-- Build dynamic sql
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(TableColumnName), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OrderBy)
FROM    zGenericOrder
WHERE   ClientID = 1 -- your client

-- Execute the select
EXEC('SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM zAddress')
```

To get a list of columns i use STRING_AGG which creates a CSV list of columns in form of: Col1,Col2,Col3. `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OrderBy)` ensures correct order.

Then you just execute the select by concatenating your column list.